# Which NGE movie package contains both "Death and Rebirth" and "The End Of Evangelion"?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion, merchandise

I want to know which *Neon Genesis Evangelion* movie package contains both *Death and Rebirth* and *The End Of Evangelion*. I already have the 26-episode run.

When searching, I found that *Neon Genesis Evangelion - Evangelion Feature Films - DTS* was including *The End of Evangelion*, that version seems to contain *Death and Rebirth* and *The End Of Evangelion*.

I want to know if that was the right version to buy/watch.

Answer (score 3):

The *DTS Evangelion Feature Film* collection seems to be correct in having *Death & Rebirth* and *The End of Evangelion*. According to the [Evangelion Wiki](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Neon_Genesis_Evangelion_media) anyway.

It's also been remastered with [*DTS* audio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTS_(sound_system)) which I think means it supports surround sound and other such systems better.